# How to pass variable from php to java jar file

Tags: java, php

I want to pass the variable from my php to my java jar file. how to do it? do i need a parameter from the java to hold the variable from my php?

```
$test = 'pass data';
exec('java -jar test.jar',$test);
```

Comment: syntax a little off  `exec('java -jar test.jar '.$test);`

Comment: @tim what do you mean by it sir?